# US Sales tax in stores, are they listed on pricetag or checkout?

Tags: usa, tax-refunds, texas

I am travelling to Texas, will (most?) stores have the total price including sales tax listed on the price tag, or is this a 'surprise' that happens while at the checkout?

Last year in New York City, I did not pay any sales tax at all at some stores once they noticed I was a tourist. Is this the case in Texas as well?

I would like to know this because as a visitor in Texas I can get my sales tax back.

Comment: I suspect you may have misremembered or misunderstood the situation in New York.  As far as I know, the law doesn't exempt tourists (even international tourists) from paying sales tax.  Your purchase may have been tax-exempt for some other reason, but not simply because you were a tourist.

Comment: Texas and Louisiana are the exceptions.  See the answers.  NY City has exemptions on clothing items under $110.  NJ has no tax on any clothing item

Answer (score 18):

The United States does not have a national sales tax, such as VAT, and you're not able to get a refund from the Federal Government of sales tax you pay on items you purchase when visiting. However, there are two states that do offer sales tax refunds for international visitors, [Louisiana](http://www.louisianataxfree.com/) and [Texas](http://www.taxfreetexas.com/faq.aspx). States that don't have any sales tax are Alaska, Delaware, Montana, New Hampshire, and Oregon.

Sales tax it not included in the price shown on an item, but is calculated and added at the point of sale. The rate varies throughout the country, as both the State and local government can levy sales tax. You would have to ask in the locale you visit, or check in advance using online tools such as this [Sales Tax Calculator.](http://www.calculator.net/sales-tax-calculator.html)

And, as you experienced and as @phoog points out:

> It should be noted that many states that have sales tax nonetheless
>   give tax-free status to certain categories of items. For example, in
>   New York State, clothing and footware costing less than $110 is exempt
>   from sales tax.

Comment: It should be noted that many states that have sales tax nonetheless give tax-free status to certain categories of items.  For example, in New York State, clothing and footware costing less than $110 is exempt from sales tax.

Comment: @phoog Not for the whole state.  Just in those localities that provide local tax exemption: https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/publications/sales/pub718c.pdf  Outside those exemptions the items are subject to sales tax just on the local level

Comment: Often non-prepared food (bananas, meat, bread, etc) are tax free, however prepared-food (ie. restaurants) are taxable.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I've not seen any supermarket charge sales tax on unprepared or unprocessed foods.

Comment: @Karlson As with everything in the US, it's [state-dependent](http://taxfoundation.org/blog/which-states-tax-groceries). Alabama, Arkansas, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Kansas, Mississippi, Missouri, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Utah, Virginia, and West Virginia all have grocery food taxes, although many tax them at a lower rate than other purchases.

Comment: While the rate in Texas can theoretically vary, it's going to be 8.25% everywhere.

Comment: As long as we're pointing out items that are exempt from taxes, gasoline (petrol) prices are inclusive of all taxes so if the sign says $1.999/gallon then that's it (assuming you pay cash, some stations charge more to credit card customers)

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Depends.  Some may have "Pay Same Cash or Credit" some may advertise Cash/Debit Price, so that sign may mean different things.

Comment: @chrylis False.  https://www.comptroller.texas.gov/taxes/sales/city.php

Comment: @Karlson Strange. I've never actually seen an applied tax rate lower than the limit.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor If I recall, it's actually illegal (or against TOS?) to charge more for credit cards.  What the store *can* do is give a discount for cash.  (Which is almost exactly the same thing)

Comment: @Michael - yup, it is against the merchant's TOS to penalize a customer for using credit cards; although sadly this is common practice is some places. In Texas, perishable goods are not subject to sales tax.

Comment: @SnakeDoc - For Illinois, the State's sales tax rate (http://tax.illinois.gov/legalinformation/regs/part130/130-311.pdf) on general merchandise including "grooming and hygiene products", is 6.25%. Add local/municipal sales taxes and the total is typically 7.75% to 8.5%. It's less in some cases and as much as 11.50% in certain business districts in Cook County. The State's sales tax rate on food and medicine is 1.0%. Add local/municipal sales taxes and the total (for Food/Med) is typically 1.75%, to as much as 2.0% in Chicago. (http://www.salestaxaccountants.com/illinois-sales-tax-rate.html).

Comment: _"Sales tax it not included in the price shown on an item, but is calculated and added at the point of sale."_  Reminds me of the odd requirement to tip everywhere you go. What is it with America and lying about the price I have to pay for goods and services!

Comment: @DeanMacGregor sorry side question but is gas really 1.99 per gallon?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 some places are less than that at the moment, however those are U.S. (not Imperial) gallons.

Comment: @Michael yes, I think according to my calculations here it's about 6 dollar per US gallon. (1.55 euro per liter). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

According to the [rules](https://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=T&app=9&p_dir=F&p_rloc=172479&p_tloc=14611&p_ploc=1&pg=4&p_tac=&ti=34&pt=1&ch=3&rl=288):

> **The sales and use tax applies to each total sale, not to each item of each sale**. For example, if two items are purchased at the same time and each item is sold for $.07, then the seller must collect the tax on the total sum of $.14. Sales and use tax must be reported and remitted to the comptroller as provided by Tax Code, §151.410. When sales and use tax is collected properly under the bracket system, the seller is not required to remit any amount that is collected in excess of the sales and use tax due. Conversely, when the sales and use tax collected under the bracket system is less than the sales and use tax due on the seller's total receipts, the seller is required to remit sales and use tax on the total receipts even though the seller did not collect sales and use tax from the purchasers.

So the prices likely won't include sales tax, fuel would be the likely exception to that.

As far as tax back you can look at [TaxFree Texas site](http://www.taxfreetexas.com/default.aspx) to determine the participating locations and whether or not you can obtain a tax refund for your purchases.